# How to stop running app in background when not needed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In my app I'm using location updates in the background and this works without a problem. The issue is when the user doesn't need the location updates and goes out of the app, the app is still running in the background. I added some code to the appdelegate method:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Here I set location manager to stop updating location and also set it to nil. This doesn't solve the problem.

Is there a way for the app to behave like a normal app when the user doesn't need background updating? In this version is frustrating for the user to see the location arrow in the status bar even if the location is not updating. The location manager is stored in a singleton, so there is only one instance of manager in the whole app.

Comment: If you have stopped updating location on your location manager then you are no longer using location.  Location services may still be active for another app on the device - there is nothing you can do in your app to remove the location services icon

Comment: Im sure its my app that cause it to show the icon in status bar. If I force quit it the icon disappear. 

Also while the app is background, all the other stuf in view controller runs like normal and and it shows use of about 3% of processor just like when it is in foreground. I want to be 0% like any other normal app when it goes in background. And this behaviour is when the location is not updating, but the app still lives in background.

Comment: Do you call stopUpdatingLocation() on your location manager?